# Access / Excel crossover: Should i attach spreadsheets to records

Tags: excel, ms-access, ms-access-2007, excel-2007, office-2007

I currently have an archaic system of client records that I am trying to improve.

For each client i have a directory, in that directory i include a directory for each job. Each job has a spreadsheet that i use to store their personal details, and run calculations and costings specific to their needs.
In turn I also have word documents that are linked to their spreadsheet which automatically update accordingly. The spreadsheet is also exported as a pdf as well

I am trying to build a database of customer records in Access, straight forward enough. 
For each new customer i need to be able to add the appropriate spreadsheet to their records, update the spreadsheet accordingly with their details, use the spreadsheet to calculate their costings etc.. I do not want to enter the same information repeatedly, and would like a cohesive system, with data being passed between access and excel.

Should this be easy enough to do with the two packages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what you have described above I'd like to offer the following comments:

1. The move to an Access database is definitely a good idea and would be more efficient to how you are currently creating/storing client records/jobs.
2. I would suggest designing the database to serve as a job management & billing system too - that way you could do away with need for the individual spreadsheets. If you used the database to record/calculate costings for clients you could then also design the necessary queries/reports to do away with the Word documents as well. To give you an idea, perhaps check out this Office template: http://bit.ly/bXLXhl

However, to specifically answer your question: Access 2007 onwards has an 'attachment' field type for records that could be used to do what you're asking. But, re-iterating what I mentioned above, I don't think doing it this way would provide you with any of the enhanced benefits of using a database.

Regards,

David

Comment: So far as I can tell, the Attachment field really has benefit only if you're integrating with Sharepoint. But I could be wrong on that, as I have chosen not to develop in A2007 (A2010 will be a different story).

Comment: Hi David,

Cheers for the great advice, greatly appreciated.
The template you recommended is the point in the right direction I needed.

Thanks alot,

Noel